# Spring JDBCTemplate Update issue

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbctemplate

In my table definition, there is a column with int data type. If a value is "0", I want jdbcTemplate update method to update this field with "NULL" instead of "0" by default.

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION "
                + "SET ObserverId = ?," + "ObservationDate = ?,"
                + "PointCuring = ?"
                + " WHERE locationId = ? AND ObservationStatus = 0",
                new Object[] { new Integer(newObservation.getObserverId()),
                        newObservation.getObservationDate(),
                        new Integer(newObservation.getLocationId()) });
```

The code snippet above runs well when the `Point Curing` is `not NULL`. However, how can it be stored as `NULL` in the database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are getting NUll Pointer Exception.

Try this

```
Integer locId = null;

if(newObservation.getLocationId() != null) {
 locId = new Integer(newObservation.getLocationId());
 if(locId == 0) {
   locId = null;
 }
}
```

And now pass locId here.

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION "
                + "SET ObserverId = ?," + "ObservationDate = ?,"
                + "PointCuring = ?"
                + " WHERE locationId = ? AND ObservationStatus = 0",
                new Object[] { new Integer(newObservation.getObserverId()),
                        newObservation.getObservationDate(),
                        locId) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the return type of getLocationId() is int the below code will work.  The proper fix would be to change the signature of getLocationId() to Integer and make sure the code that initializes it sets it to NULL instead of 0

```
this.jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION "
                + "SET ObserverId = ?," + "ObservationDate = ?,"
                + "PointCuring = ?"
                + " WHERE locationId = ? AND ObservationStatus = 0",
                new Object[] { new Integer(newObservation.getObserverId()),
                        newObservation.getObservationDate(),
                        newObservation.getLocationId() == 0 ? null : new Integer(newObservation.getLocationId()) });
```